# What's the point of using Time Crystal when USS Discovery has got Spore Drive?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In the recent episode S02E13 of *Star Trek: Discovery*,

> USS Discovery is being sent to the future to protect the Sphere Archive using the Time Crystal and the Red Angel.

What's the point of that, when USS Discovery has a Spore Drive which can take the ship anywhere in the Mycelial Network, which spans across multiple universes let alone time and space?

Comment: Can they control time jumps with the Spore Drive? I don't think it was shown as possible so far (to control the jumps, not to do it in general).

Comment: @ShanaTar They were making use of Time Crystal which was fully alien to them. In contrast, they had access to full Spore Drive logs. With litte research they could definitely replicate the previous time jump.

Answer (score 4):

The entirety of my answer, I think, would be a spoiler, so...

> The spore drive was never established as capable of time travel. Since it could take Discovery anywhere, there is no place it could be sent from which it could not eventually return. The only one-way trip would be through time, into the far future. Not discussed in dialogue (so far as I recall) is the assumption that the controlling intelligence isn't able to invent or co-opt a method of time travel in order to return to the series "present" or even "past" to become an even bigger menace.

Comment: When USS Discovery returned from the mirror universe, it landed into the future when Klingons had almost already won the war.

Comment: @AvengeTheFallen I forgot that. I'm open to correcting my answer. However, Discovery didn't travel that far into the future, and although they were able to navigate the Discovery in space with some reliability, the time displacement was uncontrolled and only happened as they traveled between universes.

Comment: Control just needs to get a Time Crystal.

Comment: @JerryNixon-TOS Control would also need to know _when_ to travel to.

Comment: @Joe I guess one option would be to travel back in time to just after Discovery intercepted the sphere and take the information from it then.  Though it might end up looking like the scene in Rick & Morty where 1000 people all show up to try to kill Hitler or stop people from killing Hitler.   I can't remember if there was something about the Sphere that would prevent Control from taking its data before it met Discovery.